# Solutions to questions in "Categories for the Working Mathematician"

Tags: reference-request, category-theory

Does anyone have solutions for the exercises in "Categories for the Working Mathematician"? I'm working my way through them, and want to check my answers.

Comment: There's a whole section on the creation of limits! (Ch. V §1)

Comment: Sorry, you're right. My mistake, should have read the contents a bit more carefully. Have removed that part from the question.

Answer (score 6):

It's probably a bit late for Ben, but this nice set of [notes on CWM](http://www.math.toronto.edu/stefand/CWM_notes.pdf). has appeared since he asked the question.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is interested, I also wrote down solutions to exercises in Chapters 1, 2 and 3 (so far).

You can find them here: https://positron0802.wordpress.com/categories-for-the-working-mathematician-mac-lane/